# websockets in meteor fails

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor app running works fine in local server when we run the project and run once again it takes so much time to load the project.And in some times displays the error in web console as websocket error.Please help me.

Comment: Toomuch time to load the web page.

Comment: When you run the app in production are you publishing a lot of data (e.g. is `autopublish` on)?

Comment: Autopublish is removed.@David Weldon